# Getting shorts from an integer

Tags: bit-manipulation

I'm supposed to pack some shorts into a 32 bit integer. It's a homework assignment that will lead into a larger idea of compression/decompression.

I don't have any problems understanding how to pack the shorts into an integer, but I am struggling to understand how to get each short value stored within the integer.

So, for example, I store the values 2, 4, 6, 8 into the integer. That means I want to print them in the same order I input them.

How do you go about getting these values out from the integer?

EDIT: Shorts in this context refers to an unsigned two-byte integer.

Comment: Can you explain what a "short" is in this context? (Can't help but thinking of the wedgies you're going to give those poor ints)

Comment: A short being a two byte integer. I'll add that into the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Craig corrected me, short is a 16 bit variable, therfore only 2 shorts can fit in one int, so here's my answer retrieving shorts:

```
2|4
000000000000001|00000000000000100
00000000000000100000000000000100
131076
```

denoting first as the left-most variable and last as the right-most variable, getting the short variable would like like this:

```
int x = 131076; //00000000000000100000000000000100 in binary
short last = x  & 65535; // 65535= 1111111111111111
short first= (x >> 16) & 65535;
```

and here's my previous answer fixed for compressing chars (8 bit variables):
Let's assume the first char is the one the start on the MSB and the last one is the one that ends on the LSB:

```
2|4|6|8
00000001|00000010|000000110|00001000
000000010000001000000011000001000
33818120
```

So, in this example the first char is 2 (0010), followed by 4 (0100), 6 (0110) and last: 8 (1000).

so to get the compressed numbers back one could use this code:

```
int x = 33818120; //00000010000001000000011000001000 in binary
char last = x  & 255; // 255= 11111111
char third = (x >> 8) & 255;
char second = (x >> 16) & 255;
char last = (x >> 24) & 255;
```

Comment: OP added comment to clarify that "short" is [std def of] 16 bits.  So, masking against 255 and producing 4 numbers doesn't work--that assumes char.  I can see the confusion, based on OP's 2,4,6,8 in question, but that's what we're here for.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. I think I feel a much clearer on the matter now. I wasn't thinking clearly when I wrote the post, so I just threw out 2, 4, 6 ,8 as just random numbers to be stored. In reality, only two would have been stored :^)

Answer (score 0):

This would be more interesting with char [as you'd get 4].  But, you can only pack *two* shorts into a single int.  So, I'm a bit mystified by this as to what the instructor was thinking.

Consider a union:

```
union combo {
    int u_int;
    short u_short[2];
    char u_char[4];
};

int
getint1(short s1,short s2)
{
    union combo combo;

    combo.u_short[0] = s1;
    combo.u_short[1] = s2;

    return combo.u_int;
}

short
getshort1(int val,int which)
{
    union combo combo;

    combo.u_int = val;

    return combo.u_short[which];
}
```

Now consider encoding/decoding with shifts:

```
unsigned int
getint2(unsigned short s1,unsigned short s2)
{
    unsigned int val;

    val = s1;
    val <<= 16;
    val |= s2;

    return val;
}

unsigned short
getshort2(unsigned int val,int which)
{

    val >>= (which * 16);

    return val & 0xFFFF;
}
```

The unsigned code above will probably do what you want.

But, the next uses signed values and probably won't work as well because you may have mixed signs between s1/s2 and encoding/decoding that may present problems

```
int
getint3(short s1,short s2)
{
    int val;

    val = s1;
    val <<= 16;
    val |= s2;

    return val;
}

short
getshort3(int val,int which)
{

    val >>= (which * 16);

    return val & 0xFFFF;
}
```